# d3 selection merge with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I want to update a circle and text element at the same time. I was able to make it work with only the circle:

https://plnkr.co/edit/FckQcVd1EkYLoZggmJN4

However, when I try adding a wrapping `g` to contain the `circle` and `text` it doesn't update properly.

https://plnkr.co/edit/EtL11O5qQph0xAeu88mu?p=preview

Any insight how to fix it?